# Ktor OAuth not working when grant_type is password

Tags: kotlin, authentication, oauth, ktor, clientcredential

I implemented OAuth authorization in my kotlin Ktor backend.

When using `grant_type = client_credentials`, everything works as expected.

However, when using `grant_type = password`, it does not even execute the body of `loadTokens`.

Breakpoints inside `loadTokens` in the `client_credentials` example do hit, in the password example, `loadTokens` hits a few times but nothing inside.
There is also no auth request logged for the `tokenClient` in the second example, even though log level has been configured.

This one works:

```kotlin
if (user == null) {
  loadTokens {
    val tokens = tokenClient.submitForm<FaOAuthResult>("https://sandbox.xxx.io/oauth/token",
      Parameters.build {
        append("grant_type", "client_credentials")
        append("client_id", "xxx")
        append("client_secret", "xxx")
    })

    BearerTokens(
      accessToken = tokens.access_token,
      refreshToken = tokens.access_token
    )
  }
```

And this one doesn't:

```kotlin
else {
  loadTokens {
    val tokens =
      tokenClient.submitForm<FaOAuthResult>("https://sandbox.xxx.io/oauth/token",
        Parameters.build {
          append("grant_type", "password")
          append("client_id", "xxx")
          append("client_secret", "xxx")
          append("username", user.finapiUserId!!)
          append("password", user.finapiPassword!!)
        })

        BearerTokens(
          accessToken = tokens.access_token,
          refreshToken = tokens.access_token
        )
     }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your problem using the Keycloak. Here is the gist for my code https://gist.github.com/Stexxe/6b5c94f9afcabc20a3dc2ad844e6ef2c.

Comment: As I see you have a condition inside a configuration for a Bearer provider. Could you please post a complete code snippet?